# Method argument not taking generic that implements an interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, implements

I'm having a weird issue here it seems. I have an interface, known as `Sortable`. I then have another class, like so:

```
public class LeftSort {

    private List<Sortable> list;

    public <T extends Sortable> LeftSort(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

However when I go to make another class, called `Foo`, like so:

```
public class Foo implements Sortable {}
```

When doing the following in a JUnit test:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
// Initialise... blah blah.

LeftSort sorter = new LeftSort(list);
```

I receive the following error:

> The constructor LeftSort(List<Foo>) is undefined.

I swear you're able to use interfaces in generics like I have done so. Is there anything I've done wrong here?

I've also messed around with doing `private List<? extends Sortable> list;` too but to no avail.

**Edit: Please make note in the future to check which class your actually importing prior to complaining like me. I simply had the wrong class imported (Foo is just the name I gave it online, it was actually Test that I so smartly decided to use...)**

Answer (score 2):

Note that your constructor doesn't compile actually:

```
public <T extends Sortable> LeftSort(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

To accept any subclass of `Sortable`, use the [Upper Bounded Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)`<? extends Sortable>` :

```
public class LeftSort {

    private List<? extends Sortable> list;

    public LeftSort(List<? extends Sortable> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm... This still seems to give me the same error.

Comment: I think that you have another issue so.Try to post all relevant code to understand the problem.

Comment: No, no, I just realised. Such an idiot... I had the wrong class imported because it's a JUnit test file and my real class was "Test", which has the same name.... Thankyou for your time.

Comment: It was an issue finally :) Great for you. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the generic type is defined for the whole class as shown below:

```
public class LeftSort<T extends Sortable> {
    private List<T> list;
    public LeftSort(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

This way you can instantiate `LeftSort` with `new ListSort<>(list)` (assuming you're using Java 7+).

Comment: "Usually" but not always.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the error I get [when I try to compile it](https://ideone.com/d3Mtkh):

```
Main.java:13: error: incompatible types: List<T> cannot be converted to List<Sortable>
        this.list = list;
                    ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Sortable declared in constructor <T>LeftSort(List<T>)
1 error
```

Which is what I'd expect, because a `List<? extends Sortable>` isn't a `List<Sortable>`.

You'd have to take a defensive copy of the list:

```
this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Or make the `list` field of a bounded type:

```
private List<? extends Sortable> list;
```

Comment: Ah pardon, my Eclipse isn't immediately telling me the error and I've done it wrong. However the other class still throws me the error when trying to instantiate...

Comment: OH MY GOD! I HAD THE WRONG CLASS IMPORTED

Comment: I thankyou for your help nonetheless Andy and for time wasted. I've checked the question to be closed because while your answers still very much answer a failure in my question, the whole thing shouldn't of been posed in the first place.